# GMail API aliases.getSendAs().get(0).getDisplayName returns empty (only for 0, not for the next ones)

Tags: java, gmail-api

I'm using Java GMail API and everything is working good for sending e-mails, collecting data from my profile, etc.

The only problem is that, while I can get the Signature for my 0-th element of the list of SendAs aliases, I can't get the Display Name: it returns an empty String. Both work for the other aliases (get(1) and subsequent numbers). It seems that the problem is on 0, tried on different authenticated users with Name set and it remains the same.

```
ListSendAsResponse aliases = service.users().settings().sendAs().list("me").execute(); 
SendAs mimmo = aliases.getSendAs().get(0);
actualsign = mimmo.getSignature();
sendername = mimmo.getDisplayName();
```

Comment: Is that because "alias 0" means "standard account settings"?

Comment: If it is so, why shouldn't it work and show the display name, if it correctly shows Signature?

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail API, there are two different ways  to [retrieve alias(es)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.Get.html):

`getSendAs()` and `SendAs.Get(java.lang.String userId,java.lang.String sendAsEmail)`

The first one returns you a list of all alias, the second returns you one alias ressource - the one with the specified `userId` and `sendAsEmail` parameters.

If what you want to do it to retrieve the first element of the `getSendAs()` response, you should do it with `getSendAs()[0]` and not with the [Java method](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/arraylist/arraylist_get.php) `get`.

Sample:

```
SendAs mimmo = aliases.getSendAs()[0];
System.out.println(mimmo.getDisplayName());
```

It is always useful to test with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/list) what response a method returns. Thereby, the `userId` can be set to `me`.

Comment: I forgot to add a piece of code, I updated my first message. Your code won't work, I think because I've obtained it as a ListSendAsResponse as you can see in the first post. How should I proceed?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be `mimmo.getDisplayName()`

Comment: Still doesn't work, since aliases.getSendAs() gives me a List<SendAs>

Comment: Try a different approach: `for (SendAs alias: aliases.getSendAs()) {
System.out.println(alias.getDisplayName());
    }
}`

Comment: It prints correctly the Display Names of the 1,2,3-th aliases, but not of the 0-th.It's blank...

Comment: Maybe you accidentally created an alias with an empty string as a name?

Comment: It should be the first e-mail (not alias), and it has the correct name when I use it from GMail web app and write mails. It works good for the signature, but not for the display name